# How to validate numbers in a webform custom composite element

Tags: webforms

I have a Webform with a custom composite, and there I have a element which type is Number and i want to validate this element.

If I check required when the field is empty it show a message that the field is required, but if I put letters in the field show the same message when it should be that the field is not valid because it has letters.

I know how to do this with a textfield element but this element is not inside the custom composite with a regular expression . And even if i change the custom composite element from Number to Textfield I can not do it this, can not be validated individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add regular expressions for elements in a custom composite by going to the *General* tab of the custom composite, then adding your regular expression in the custom properties field for an element within the *Custom composite settings* section.

This link may be of use:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3162515

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting validations just create a number type field. And inside the number field of the custom composite element, `you can not enter the letters`, only numbers can be entered so no concept/need for validating against letters.